# What is the purpose of the symlinks within the include and local directories in a python virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

What is the purpose of the symlinks automatically created within `include` and `local` in a virtualenv?

When I run:

```
virtualenv myVirtualEnv
```

It creates the following directory structure and symlinks:

```
myVirtualEnv/
├── bin
├── include
│   └── python2.7 -> /usr/include/python2.7
├── lib
└── local
    ├── bin -> ../bin
    ├── include -> ../include
    └── lib -> ../lib
```

Why is it important for the virtual environment to track `/usr/include/python2.7` or have additional references to its own directories? Are they ever anything different than what they are set to here?

Comment: I assume the `local` symlinks are to handle scripts that include `/local` in the hashbang. Have you read [the documentation for `virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: I'm not sure but since your virtual environment is based off of your built in python version (python2.7) it is using those /usr/include files. If you changed your virtualenv version of python (using -p flag) it should be a symlink to a different include dir. Generally, Id believe this is to save space on your hdd because there's no reason to copy these files.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've been looking through the docs and haven't found much regarding this, or at least not when searching for terms such as 'symlink' and 'local'. The hashbang idea makes sense. It's weird though, because both the `include` and `local` directories are dropped if you do `virtualenv myVirtualEnv -p python3`